# Button template - adding grid on rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is my template for button in XAML code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="templateOfButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Rectangle Height="200" Width="200">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="kot.jpg"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

For now, there is only rectangle filled with Image. I'd  like to add **grid** on this rectangle, so I can not only fiil it using Image, but place Image **on** rectangle and add another objects like Textblocks in proper column/row. Does anyone know how to do this? Is it possible?

I think this picture explains what I'd like to do: [Link](https://ibb.co/kmStAe)

Comment: You should always include in your question what did you try so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a ControlTemplate that can be applied on a Button that would do what is shown in the picture:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="templateOfButton" TargetType="Button">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="1" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="2" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="3" />
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many samples out on creating your own control template.  You can Aside from just a template, you can get binding to your objects with DependencyProperties.

[WPF c# setting style with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50835495/wpf-c-sharp-setting-style-with-parameters/50838193#50838193)

This allows an object with those settings applied vs fixed values in a template.