XAML databinding fails when set in the code behind
In a WPF project, I have a UserControl called RectZone
which starts with
<UserControl x:Class="SublimeTriptych.control.RectZone"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:control="clr-namespace:SublimeTriptych.control"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             AllowDrop="True"  xml:lang="fr-FR"
             Drop="DropRectZone" DragOver="DragOverRectZone" DragEnter="DragEnterRectZone" DragLeave="DragLeaveRectZone"
             MinHeight="800" MinWidth="400"
             d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Background="{Binding ZoneImage, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=control:RectZone}}"/>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black"
                   Visibility="{Binding GuideVisibility, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=control:RectZone}}"
                   StrokeThickness="{Binding FrameThickness, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=control:RectZone}}">
            <Rectangle.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="100" Color="{Binding DropShadowColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=control:RectZone}}" />
            </Rectangle.Effect>
        </Rectangle>

        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="#83808080" Visibility="{Binding TitleVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=control:RectZone}}">
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding ActualWidth, StringFormat=N2, FallbackValue=200, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=control:RectZone}}"
                     FontSize="{Binding StatusFontSize, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=control:RectZone}}"/>
                <Run Text="X"
                     FontSize="{Binding StatusFontSize, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=control:RectZone}}"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding ActualHeight, StringFormat=N2, FallbackValue=450, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=control:RectZone}}"
                     FontSize="{Binding StatusFontSize, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=control:RectZone}}"/>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=control:RectZone}}"
                       FontSize="{Binding StatusFontSize, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=control:RectZone}}"
                       Visibility="{Binding LogVisibility, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=control:RectZone}}"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=control:RectZone}}"
                       FontSize="{Binding StatusFontSize, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=control:RectZone}}"
                       />
            </StackPanel>

In the code behind I have property dependencies defined:
public int FrameThickness
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(FrameThicknessProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FrameThicknessProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty FrameThicknessProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(FrameThickness), typeof(int), typeof(RectZone), new PropertyMetadata(1));

public string Title
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Title), typeof(string), typeof(RectZone), new PropertyMetadata("title"));

public ImageBrush? ZoneImage     
{
    get { return (ImageBrush)GetValue(ZoneImageProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ZoneImageProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ZoneImageProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ZoneImage), typeof(ImageBrush), typeof(RectZone), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public Visibility LogVisibility
{
    get { return (Visibility)GetValue(LogVisibilityProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LogVisibilityProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty LogVisibilityProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(LogVisibility), typeof(Visibility), typeof(RectZone), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));

I believe all of this is correct, VS2022 designer show no problem, nevertheless, I get the XAML binding failures:

text version for one of them:
Severity: Error
Count: 4
Data Context: Visibility
Binding Path: TitleVisibility
Target: RectZone.TitleVisibility
Target Type: Visibility
Description File: TitleVisibility property not found on object of type Visibility

The error messages are not leading to the source of the problem.
I use RectZone in another user control, ProjectVarioView, which has in the code behind the following code.
There I have a number of RectZones determined in the ViewModel, but I set the data binding in the code behind:
It seems that all the errors are related to the databinding (total 7) I set in SetGrid and AddZone:
private void ViewModelChanged(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.PropertyName != nameof(ViewModel)) return;
    SetGrid(GridZonesContainer, ViewModel.CompoConf.Cols, ViewModel.CompoConf.Rows, MarginWidth);
}

private void SetGrid(Grid gridBase, int cols, int rows, int marginWidth)
{
    cols = cols * 2 + 1;
    rows = rows * 2 + 1;
    var star = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    var margin = new GridLength(marginWidth);
    var marginBinding = new Binding("MarginWidth") { Source = ViewModel.Margins, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
    gridBase.SetBinding(MarginWidthProperty, marginBinding);

    for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
        gridBase.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition
            { Width = x % 2 != 0 ? star : margin });
    for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
        gridBase.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition
            { Height = y % 2 != 0 ? star : margin });
    for (int x = 1, datax = 0; x < cols; x += 2, datax++)
    for (int y = 1, datay = 0; y < rows; y += 2, datay++)
        AddZone(x, y, datax, datay);
}

private void AddZone(int gridx, int gridy, int datax, int datay)
{
    //ZoneImage = "{Binding ZonesData[gridx, gridy].Image, Mode=TwoWay}"
    //Title = "{Binding  ZonesData[gridx, gridy].Title, Mode=TwoWay}"
    //TitleVisibility = "{Binding TitleVisibility, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    //GuideVisibility = "{Binding GuideVisibility}"
    //LogVisibility = "{Binding LogVisibility}"
    //DebugMode = "{Binding DebugMode, Mode=TwoWay}" />

    var mz = new RectZone();
    var imageBinding = new Binding("Image") {Source = ViewModel.ZonesData[datax, datay].LastVignette, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay};
    mz.SetBinding(RectZone.ZoneImageProperty, imageBinding);
    var titleBinding = new Binding("Title") {Source = ViewModel.ZonesData[datax, datay].Name, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
    mz.SetBinding(RectZone.TitleProperty, titleBinding);
    var titleVisibilityBinding = new Binding("TitleVisibility") { Source = ViewModel.TitleVisibility };
    mz.SetBinding(RectZone.TitleVisibilityProperty, titleVisibilityBinding);
    var guideVisibilityBinding = new Binding("GuideVisibility") { Source = ViewModel.GuideVisibility };
    mz.SetBinding(RectZone.GuideVisibilityProperty, guideVisibilityBinding);
    var logVisibilityBinding = new Binding("LogVisibility") { Source = ViewModel.LogVisibility };
    mz.SetBinding(RectZone.LogVisibilityProperty, logVisibilityBinding);
    var debugModeBinding = new Binding("DebugMode") { Source = ViewModel.DebugMode, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay };
    mz.SetBinding(RectZone.DebugModeProperty, debugModeBinding);

    GridZonesContainer.Children.Add(mz);
    Grid.SetRow(mz, gridy);
    Grid.SetColumn(mz, gridx);
    _ZonesList.Add(mz);
}

The ViewModel has this property, an array of other ViewModels:
public ZoneViewModel[,] ZonesData
{
    get => _zonesData;
    set
    {
        if (Equals(value, _zonesData)) return;
        _zonesData = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

and:
public Visibility TitleVisibility
{
    get => _titleVisibility;
    set
    {
        if (value == _titleVisibility) return;
        _titleVisibility = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public Visibility GuideVisibility
{
    get => _guideVisibility;
    set
    {
        if (value == _guideVisibility) return;
        _guideVisibility = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public Visibility LogVisibility
{
    get => _logVisibility;
    set
    {
        if (value == _logVisibility) return;
        _logVisibility = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

and ZoneViewModel implements this interface:
public interface IMediaViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public StopwatchBag Sw { get; }
    public Uri URI { get; }
    public ImageSize ImageSize { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Filepath { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public long SizeBytes { get; set; }
    public ImageBrush LastVignette { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyList<Directory>? Metadata { get; set; }
    public bool HasMetadata { get; }
    public bool HasVignettes { get; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> MetaDic { get; }
}

What am I doing wrong ?

RelativeSource sets the source object of a Binding, it does not "define the datacontext". The error messages are not related to the Bindings in the UserControl's XAML that you are showing here, They seem to come from the Bindings of the UserControl's properties. We do however not know how these Bindings look like and how the control's DataContext is actually set.

Couple that can help.  You need a STYLE definition based on your CLASS that will know about its dependency properties.  Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50835495/wpf-c-sharp-setting-style-with-parameters/50838193#50838193
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54318787/reusing-wpf-user-control-by-parametrizing-it-does-not-work/54319851#54319851

@Clemens You were right, I believe I am doing something wrong in the databinding I set in another code behind. OP updated.

The problem is in the Binding instance creation; I misused the Path (string arg in the constructor), and the Source should be the ViewModel containing the property (indicated in the Path).
In practice, for instance, instead of:
var imageBinding = new Binding("Image")
    {Source = ViewModel.ZonesData[datax, datay].LastVignette,
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay};

I should do:
var imageBinding = new Binding("LastVignette")
    {Source = ViewModel.ZonesData[datax, datay],
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay};

Same for the 6 other bindings.
