# WPF see design time binds in UserlControl without MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm designing a new `UserControl` for my project and it doesn't use MVVM, because I want to bind its properties directly on the parent XAML. So I have a bunch of dependency properties and my binds are like this: `Text="{Binding Title, ElementName=ThisControl}"`. All of them works at run time, but I really can't get it to work in design time.

I've seen many solutions here at SO, but all of them are for when you have the binds to a ViewModel property. '

I tried setting up their initial value on the properties themselves and on the constructor, but they do not show in design time. Is there any way to do that?

-- UPDATE --

Here's an example of a `UserControl`

--XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="QualityChecker.Client.UserInterface.Pages.QuickAudit.Controls.InfoCard"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
             TextElement.FontWeight="Regular"
             TextElement.FontSize="13"
             TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal" 
             TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Auto"   
             Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
             FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFont}"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Name="ThisControl"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <materialDesign:Card Width="350" Margin="8 2 4 16" Height="180">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            ...
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignHeadline5TextBlock}" Margin="16 16 16 8" Text="{Binding Title, ElementName=ThisControl}"></TextBlock>
             ...
         </Grid>
    </materialDesign:Card>
</UserControl>
```

-- .cs

```
public CustomUserControl()
{
    Title = "My Initial value"
}

public string Title
{
    get => (string)GetValue(TitleProperty);
    set => SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Title), typeof(string),
    typeof(InfoCard), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("Initial Value"));
```

Comment: Are you using DesignInstance/DesignData?

Comment: Where exactly is `ThisControl` being defined?

Comment: are you using `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `UserControl` ? because if you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and then in XAML use UserControl and It's properties you'll see instant design time changes.

Comment: And you should include code of what you have done :(

Comment: @RaoHammasHussain I didn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` because I'm using only Dependency properties, like in the example I updated.

Comment: @MarkFeldman I just updated the question with a sample code.

Comment: @asaf92 I tried to use DesignInstance, but as far as I understood, it's for use when you have a ViewModel, so you can make a design time instance for the bindings, but since my binds relatively to the control itself, it doesn't work

Comment: @RBasniak yeah you're right, I missed the fact that you're not binding to another class. Maybe you need to use the `AffectRender` option in the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadataoptions?view=netframework-4.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is going to to work the way you want it to. The problem is that designer never creates an instance of the class you are editing, only its child classes (and even then, only the ones that have already been successfully compiled). It also doesn't instantiate static code, so the DPs never get created either. The reason data binding works is because again, you're not binding anything to the class itself, you're binding its child controls to the design data.

There are workarounds, like explicitly creating an instance of the class and setting it as it's own design-time ddata context with `d:DataContext`, but they're really messy and will mess with data-bindings higher up the logical tree. Best thing to do is place a copy of your control in a parent window while you're designing and visualize it that way.

Comment: This is my first reusable user control with databinding. Am I taking the right approach? It's not possible that people who create custom commercial controls work like this, without seeing them in the designer. I know this is another question, but it would be very kind if you tell me that. I didn't find any good examples for something like this.

Comment: That's a bit like saying it's not possible for people who write C# to not see the changes immediately in their application while it's running. XAML files aren't static layouts in the traditional sense, they get compiled into BAML. If you look at your UserControl you'll see it's declared as a `partial` class, that's because there's more code being added to that class by the XAML side of things after it's compiled. It's also why `InitializeComponent` gets called i.e. to do the initialization for that stuff.

Comment: To answer your question though, UserControl's aren't used in WPF anywhere near as much as they were in Winforms (say). When I do use them myself, I design with static data initially, then switch over to DPs when I'm done. If I need to work on a control later I temporarily host it in a parent control. Other developers use tools like Blender for their design instead. I suspect you'll find though that in reality, most devs just write the XAML by hand and run it to see what it looks like.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that the VC designer is almost universally regarded as total crap. The Live Visual Tree, on the other hand, is actually pretty good in comparison, so if a control isn't looking right you can generally use that to figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

The following two samples I have offered in the past might help.

[One sample custom user control, 3 dependency properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50835495/wpf-c-sharp-setting-style-with-parameters/50838193#50838193)

[Another for a customized button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274956/wpf-custom-button-best-approach/13276319#13276319)

To visually get what you are looking for WHILE IN DESIGN TIME is done with control templates and doing TemplateBinding for the parts in question.

I think the first example would be a better match via dependency properties, and in this one, I offer 3 different control template layouts, so you can pick whichever one works best for you.

The second shows begin-to-end on for a customized button.

The premise is that your custom control is derived from a given known control, even if derived from "User Control" and you have all your extra properties.  Then you define a control template BASED-ON YOUR custom control type, not the generic "UserControl".  The based on allows the XAML to properly detect the custom properties that are available that you want to expose in your final output of the control.  Then, by setting a style for your control based on the control template, each time you put onto a form, it will show values set at design-time.

If you define a

```
<UserControl .. properties you expect... >
```

but don't do via

```
   <xmlRefNamespaceToYourClass:YourCustomClass … properties will now be visible … >
```

you wont see your expected properties to expose for display.

Each of the respective samples work and are pretty well commented on how/where things go and why.